# Set jQuery UI dialog's position relative to the element that opened it

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to position a jQueryUI dialog above the element that was clicked to trigger its open.

I've tried the following, but it isn't working.

```
$(function() {
    dialog = $( "#gridDialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Close": function(event, ui) {
            dialog.dialog( "close" );
         }
    },
    open: function(event,ui){
        dialog.dialog( "option", "position", {at: "left top", of: event } );
    }
  });           
});
```

Comment: My bad, apparently the "event" passed to the open function doesn't work with the "position" function.  I set the source object to a data element of the dialog in the "onclick" event that opens the dialog, read that data element in the "open" function and used that for the reference for "position:
target=$( ".gridDialog" ).data("target");
dialog.dialog( "option", "position", {my:"left top", at: "left top", of: target } );

Comment: If you solved a puzzle then either delete the question or answer the question yourself so that it doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 8):

The issue with your approach is that you're trying to position the dialog inside it's own [`open()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) method, which receives a *custom jQuery UI* event object, that doesn't have `pageX` and `pageY` properties which is expected by the jQuery UI [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) method.

Instead if you set the position of dialog inside the `click` event handler before opening it, You can  simply pass`this`, or the *click* event object as the value of [`position()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option's *of* property.

For example:

```js
 $("#dialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false
 });
 $(".box").click(function() {
   $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", {
     at: "left top",
     of: this // this refers to the cliked element
   }).dialog("open");
 });
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="left" class="box"></div>
<div id="right" class="box"></div>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent ! thank you TJ